# How self works inside a class in python

Tags: python

I need some help with the following code:

```
import logging

class TestLoggin:

    def __init__(self):
        # Create the Logger
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # Create the Handler for logging data to a file
        logger_handler = logging.FileHandler('output.log')
        logger_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # Create a Formatter for formatting the log messages
        logger_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',  datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

        # Add the Formatter to the Handler
        logger_handler.setFormatter(logger_formatter)

        # Add the Handler to the Logger
        self.logger.addHandler(logger_handler)
```

The logging module works fine when the setup is inside the `__init__` method. But if I try to remove it to a new method, as below:

```
import logging

class TestLoggin:

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = self.setup_logger(output_path)

    def example_using_logger(self):
        self.logger.error('it will raise an error')    

    def setup_logger(self, output_path):
        # Create the Logger
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # Create the Handler for logging data to a file
        logger_handler = logging.FileHandler(output_path)
        logger_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # Create a Formatter for formatting the log messages
        logger_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',  datefmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

        # Add the Formatter to the Handler
        logger_handler.setFormatter(logger_formatter)

        # Add the Handler to the Logger
        return logger.addHandler(logger_handler)
```

And try to use the logger module `self.logger.error('it will raise an error')`, I got the following error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'`.

I know the raised error is because `logger` is not recognized as part of the module, but as just a new variable. That is because I didn't grasp the fundamental of `self`. I'm new to Python, so I need some help here: How can I fix this, and the *why* of the problem. This last one would help me to understand a little more about the `self`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has nothing to do with self. `logger.addHandler` doesn't return anything, so you can't return the result of that from your setup method. Just return the logger.

Comment: into setup_logger you return result of the addHandler, not logger istance, so you get attribute error.

Comment: `return logger`, not `logger.addHandler(logger_handler)`. `Logger.addHandler()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: And consider using `@staticmethod`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that logger.addHandler() isn't returning anything, so you're assigning None (returned from logger.addHandler()) to self.logger.

Try this:

```
# Add the Handler to the Logger
logger.addHandler(logger_handler)
return logger
```